# Modern browsers, progressive rendering anc CSS at bottom

Tags: css, performance, browser, stylesheet

Currently, I'm investigating several tips/recommendations for improving the performance of web sites. So, I've started with Steve Souders' excellent books (High performance web sites and even faster web sites), but I've got a couple of questions regarding some of the rules that are presented. FOr instance, chapter 5 of High performance web sites say that CSS stylesheets should be put at the top of the page because putting them at the bottom stops the progressive rendering that is performed by the browsers. According to Steve, some browsers (most notably IE) do get stuck with it and show a blank page instead of showing the items progressively. Here's the url for that test page:
http://stevesouders.com/hpws/css-bottom.php

Now, I do understand that we're talking about a book with a couple of years and that browsers (including IE) have been updated and improved. The reason I'm asking this is because I can't reproduce the behavior he mentions with any current version of FF, Chrome or IE.

Well, the thing is that Yahoo (http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#css_top) and google (https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering#PutCSSInHead) still say that.

So, what I'd like to know is if browsers have evolved in this area and this is only problematic for, say IE 8? If that is the case, why haven't yahoo and google updated their recommendations? (btw, I've tried simulating IE7 from within IE11 and still don't see the expected result that is described in the book...)

**UDPATE**One more final note: I've decided to reproduce Steve's cgi script in asp.net and I've created a simple generic handler that does the same thing as the sleep.cgi script. what I'm seeing here is that putting a stylesheet reference (which takes some time to load - I've went with 10 seconds)  inside the head ends up producing the blank page problem that is reported in the book. If you put at the end, the browser ends up rendering everything and making a second pass for applying the styles after they have been loaded. In my opinion, this makes sense because when you put the style in the header element, the browser is holding up until it gets the styles before rendering (notice that the other referenced components are still being downloaded on the background, but they're not being shown in the screen). On the other hand, when they're at the bottom, the browser will simply apply the current styles until it gets stuck in the stylesheet. WHen that happens, it will only show the html it has loaded until the stylesheet (if there are any images below it, the browser will still download them but it will only render them after the styles have been loaded).

So, after these tests, I'm starting to think that 1.) I'm missing something here or 2.) yahoo and google recommendations are no longer valid today.

Thoughts?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Am I right in understanding that you consider a FOUC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content *desirable* if it means you end up with a faster pageload? (I think it's a valid approach, just it's usually considered undesirable...)

Comment: No, that's not my point. WHat I'm saying is that the behavior described in Yahoo/Google recommendations and in Steve's books is no longer correct, ie, putting stylesheets at the bottom ends up suspending progressive rendering and you'll see a blank page. In fact, I've ended up with the inverse results, ie, if I put the stylesheet in the top of the page, and that stylesheet takes 10 seconds to download, then that's when you end up getting the blank page that is mentioned in high performance web sites. 
I understand that FOUC is not good, but I'm just looking for facts...

Comment: Ah, so less a discussion of best practice for loading pages, and more a question of whether or not there's a blank page?

Comment: MOre a question of understanding the truth. Steve's book, Google and Yahoo all say that putting the stylesheets at the end of the page means no progressive rendering and that's why you should put it on the top. For instance, here's what yahoo says: "user experience.
The problem with putting stylesheets near the bottom of the document is that it prohibits progressive rendering in many browsers, including Internet Explorer. These browsers block rendering to avoid having to redraw elements of the page if their styles change. The user is stuck viewing a blank white page." This is no longer true...

Comment: @LuisAbreu, Correct I'm having this behavior too on Chrome v34. **Put ur CSS at the bottom** if your intention is to display the page as soon as possible.

Comment: I think it is still a valid idea not to put CSS near the bottom of the page. It is not a "good user experience" to present your users a unstyled page. You can use some lightweight loading indicator instead.

Comment: I would look into people that discuss the critical rendering path. Depending on the size of your CSS you should/could inline it in a style tag at the top. There are grunt plugins for this. I think generally they say 10-14k of CSS can go inline on the page and should only be the stuff required for the layout in the top parts of the page. Then possibly include more CSS wherever you want, knowing there could be a delay in the request/load from that.

Answer (score 2):

Simply inserting a `<link>` tag in the footer is not the way to defer stylesheets. The currently accepted method is to attach it using javascript:

```
<script>
function loadStyleSheet(e){if(document.createStyleSheet)try{document.createStyleSheet(e)}catch(t){}else{var l;l=document.createElement("link"),l.rel="stylesheet",l.type="text/css",l.media="all",l.href=e,document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(l)}}loadStyleSheet("/your/stylesheet.css");
</script>
```

Optimizing your page for speed involves determining what CSS is above the fold, inlining that part in the header, and loading the main stylesheet later using the above method.

I recommend doing some searches for "above the fold css" and check out Google Pagespeed Insights.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/